# Automatically Login via SSO Connected App

Tags: single-sign-on, connected-apps, namedcredentials, jwt, loginflow

I'm trying to teach myself IAM areas I'm weak on.

I have 2 dev ed orgs.Org A - is the IDP
Org B - is the SP

I have created the SSO settings in Org B to use Org A as the IDP.In Org A, I have created the connected app.

All works well, all works great for SSO matching on federation Id. A next step, I wish to do almost an 'aloha' community cloud implementation.

I have the connected app show in the Org A app launcher but when I click it, it takes me to the Org B My Domain login URL. I can click SSO and use Org A to authenticate but what I want is that step to be automated and I automatically go into Org B

What are my next steps/topics I need to research? Is it some apex that I now need to write, something to do with login flows? I kinda just want to know the subject/topic to teach myself this next step.

I have seen various other attempts but no full answer, using named credentials and JWT exchange. Maybe that is the key?

Basically, I wish to click the app on the app launcher which will take me to Org b and automatically log me in providing I am a user on that org too, matching via federation Id.

Comment: What is the start URL in your connected app? Also if you disable the Username and Password Login option in your Org B my domain settings can also achieve this functionality

Comment: So I set the start URL as the my domain login URL.

Comment: Ahhh! Please add your solution above as an answer so I can mark it as best answer. Disabling the Username and Password login form worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable the Username and Password Login option in your Org B my domain settings, you can achieve this functionality